# How to do Git unmerge for certain branches?

Tags: git, git-merge

There are 5 branches which have been merged sequentially to `master` in the following order: Branch 1, Branch 2, Branch 3, Branch 4, Branch 5.

Now, we found out that branch 3 and branch 4 are unwanted.

I could do the following:

1. Rollback `master` before the branches have been merged.
2. Merge one by one, Branch 1, Branch 2, and Branch 5 into `master`.

Is there any better way to achieve this using git command such that branch 3, and branch 4 that have already been merged could just be excluded from `master`?

Comment: Please use appropriate Markdown formatting; don't format something as a quote if it isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you have already done:

1. Did you pushed the changes alread?

   - You can `git reset --hard` to the position before branch 3 and 4 were merged and remerge branch 5 again. This results in a history rewriting which might be intended but is generally spoken not a good idea.
   - You can revert everything up to the position where branch 3, 4 where merged and merge branch 5 again.
2. Did you not yet pushed the changes?

   - Reseting hard is still a choice but you don't have the drawbacks of history rewriting on remote
   - Reverting is also a good idea here.

The decision is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to do it without using reset? I am thinking to preserve the git log. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my answer you can use revert.